# Error when building apk with gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: react-native, gradle, gradlew

When I build the apk an error message appears like this.

[image]

But if the apk builds successfully and then installs it on the smartphone, the application crashes.

Comment: Uncomment this line `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in ./android/gradle.properties then retry to generate a new apk

Comment: @MahdiN after I install the application on the smartphone the application crashes when running

Comment: when you build your app in release mode does it crash or it crashes only when you generate an apk? can you provide more informations about your project (react-native version, libraries that you  use)

Comment: @MahdiN Problem solved, thanks bro.